# Memory issue in dlib object detector training

Tags: c++, training-data, dlib

- I am using dlib for object detection.I am training my own detector using dlib.
- But when i give more then 1000 images, data is not trained.Process is killed by system.I have searched online but didn't find any particular solution for that.
- I want to know that is there any particular pattern for giving input images or any other thing that i have to consider for training data.Is there any requirement of RAM or type of images or size of images.
- Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Without seeing any kind of code it's impossible to say what the problem might be. Maybe you are just creating a lot of objects, but never destroy them?

Comment: I am using dlib library code for training.For that i am using `train_object_detector.cpp` from dlib.

Comment: Here you can find source code for training detector http://dlib.net/train_object_detector.cpp.html

Comment: @RONAKCHAUHAN  Are you using C++ codes for training? Then try to get exception using `try` & `catch` block . Process is killed by system, it means it is not exiting normally.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with RAM.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024165/d-lib-object-detector-training/39024492#39024492